# LED Blinking Using Push button

Tags: programming, code-review

Whenever I upload the following program I am getting error message 
showing "expected initializer before interval".

Kindly Help me to solve out this probleme.

```
const byte button=2;
const byte LED=10;
bool blinking =false;//defines when blinking should occur
unsigned long blink Interval=250;// number of milliseconds for blink
unsigned long currentMillis;// variables to track millis()
unsigned long previousMillis;
void setup()
{
    pinMode(button,INPUT);
    pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
    // this code  blinks the LED
    if(blinking) {
        currentMillis =millis();// better to store in variable, for less jitter

        if((unsignedlong)(currentMillis-previousMillis) >=blinkInterval) { // enough time passed yet?
            digitalWrite(LED,!digitalRead(LED)); // shortcut to toggle the LED
            previousMillis =currentMillis;// sets the time we wait "from"
        }
    } else {
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW); // force LED off when not blinking
    }

    int reading=digitalRead(button);
    delay(50); // crude de-bouncing

    if(reading==LOW) // buttons with pull-up are pressed when LOW
    { blinking =true; }// start blinking
    else
    { blinking =false; }// stop blinking
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is `blinkInterval`, not `blink Interval`. You have an space in the name in the declaration:

```
unsigned long blinkInterval=250; // number of milliseconds for blink
// ....
if((unsigned long)(currentMillis-previousMillis) >= blinkInterval) {
```

Comment: @Josephazim. That's not a problem; that's your code. When button goes HIGH, you put `blinking=false`. You have to introduce a waiting time there, but that is a new problem.

Comment: Thanks!It worked as you suggest but now my problem is that when I keep holding the button led is blinking and when I release the button it stop.I want it to be when I hold the push button for 5 sec, then led should start blinking for 10 minute or according to the certain time.Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @Josephazim Check out my answer. It will helpful for you.

Comment: @NickGammon I think you have to check this comment section. I answered according to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fully working sketch

```
const byte button=2;                     
const byte LED=10;                 
bool blinking =false;
unsigned long blinkInterval=250;                      
unsigned long currentMillis;                        
unsigned long previousMillis;                       
void setup()
{
    pinMode(button,INPUT);
    pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{

    if(blinking) {
        currentMillis =millis();

        unsigned long blinkInterval=100;
        if((unsigned long)(currentMillis-previousMillis) >= blinkInterval) { 
            digitalWrite(LED,!digitalRead(LED)); LED
            previousMillis =currentMillis;
        }
    } else {
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW); 
    }

    int reading=digitalRead(button);
    delay(100); 

    if(reading==LOW) 
    { blinking =true; }
    else
    { blinking =false; }
}
```